# Absorption and re-emission of waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

How accurate is the slowing of electromagnetic waves in a medium to be caused by the absorption of the wave by an electron. And the electron re-emitting the waves. And therefore causing a delay in transmission in that medium.

When the wave is composed of oscillating electric and magnetic fields is incident on an electron. Wouldn't it essentially apply a force on the electron and pass through to the next electron?

Why have they explained it as though the electric and magnetic fields are momentarily stopped in their path?
How accurate is it?

```
Every photon (bundle of electromagnetic energy) travels between the interatomic void at a speed of c;
yet time delay involved in the process of being absorbed and reemitted by the atoms of the material
 lowers the net speed of transport from one end of the medium to the other. 
Subsequently, the net speed of an electromagnetic wave in any medium is somewhat less than its
 speed in a vacuum - c (3 x 108 m/s).
```

[image]

Comment: A delay in the transmission is not the same as the deceleration of the propagating wave. The former is only a phase change, the latter is the change of the speed of propagation. I wouldn't try to construct such a model because it tries to describe atoms and electrons but without any quantum mechanics.

Comment: Yes, and the latter causes the former.

Comment: And it literally says. The net speed of EM radiation in a medium is less of than in a vacuum. Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity, so the speed in a given direction must decrease.